# Virtual functions - where's the pointer?

Tags: c++, function, inheritance, virtual

An example to start with.

```
class A
{
    public:
    virtual const char* GetName() { return "A"; }
};

class B: public A
{
public:
    virtual const char* GetName() { return "B"; }
};

class C: public B
{
public:
    virtual const char* GetName() { return "C"; }
};

    class D: public C
{
public:
    virtual const char* GetName() { return "D"; }
};

int main()
{
    C cClass;
    A &rBase = cClass;
    cout << "rBase is a " << rBase.GetName() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In this particular example the output is :

rBase is a C

Here are the steps of how it works:

rBase is a pointer of type A, so it goes to class A and looks for GetName(). But GetName() is virtual there so compiler checks all classes between A and C and takes GetNAme() function from the most derived class ie C

**But, my doubt is that how will the compiler know which is the child of class A and how will it be able to move to class B and so on from Parent class to child class ? A child know it's parent but the parent doesn't know it's children (I think!).**

From my point of view the correct steps of execution should have been:

rBase is a pointer of type A, so it goes to class A and looks for GetName(). But GetName() is virtual there so the compiler checks what class the pointer is pointing to. C class object in this case, so goes to C class and checks if it has function GetName() so uses it. If the function was not present in C class (assume) the compiler can easily trace C's parent and check for the same and this could go on until it reaches back to A (assuming all classes except A doesn't contain GetName()).

Now, this seems a more logical method because moving backward (child to parent) in an inheritance tree seems more achievable than moving forward (parent to child).

Regards,

Answer (score 4):

The 2nd algorithm you describe is "correct" in that it would effectively resolve things this way.  However, the compiler uses a nice trick to fast-forward that algorithm.  Basically, it uses a lookup commonly called a [virtual method table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table), often abbreviated to "vtable".

Basically, instances of classes with virtual methods hold a pointer to their class' virtual method table.  The compiler maps virtual method names to offsets in the virtual table, such that invoking a virtual table does not need a complex algorithm: all that's necessary is an array lookup followed by a call at the resulting address.

Answer (score 2):

> rBase is a pointer of type A, so it goes to class A and looks for GetName(). But GetName() is virtual there so compiler checks all classes between A and C and takes GetNAme() function from the most derived class ie C

No, this is not how it works. The compiler when generating the code to call `virtual GetName()` through pointer to `A` just puts something like "call the 7th entry in the virtual table associated with the object". When generating a derived class that overrides `GetName()`, the compiler will put its `GetName()` implementation at this entry in the virtual table.

This way the parent class does not need to know its children. It's the children responsibility to fill their virtual table correctly.